# Is cmp certification equivalent to 4500 credit hours required for PMP?

Tags: project-management-style

I have done bachelors and wanted to know if getting cmp certification equals to 4500 credit hours required for pmp

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this assuming you mean Certified Meeting Planner. If that's not the case, my apologies.

TL;DR- Absolutely! In my opinion event planning is a highly specialized kind of project management.

My wife was an event planner for a long time. She went through the process to become a CMP and between that and watching her plan and run large events, I know she'd be an awesome project manager and that the hours she put into doing events would apply as projects.

Just remember, PMI doesn't care if you have a CMP. It is just that the same kind of work you did that qualified for a CMP application is also going to be usable in the PMP application.